# Question about the gradient vector field of a function on a flag manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$. Consider the flag manifold $M=G/T$. Let's fix a regular element $r$ of $\mathfrak{t}^*$ and identify $M$ with the coadjoint orbit $G.r$. Let $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.

I've come across the following statement "Let's denote $\nabla f$ the gradient vector field of $f$." This was without specifying any metric on $M$, why is that ? Is it because  there is a canonical metric on $M$ (if so, how it is defined), or is it because $\nabla f$  independent of the choice of a metric on $M$ ?

The definition of gradient vector field I'm using is the following

> Definition: Let (M,g) be a Riemannian manifold. The gradient of a smooth function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ with respect to the metric $g$ is the unique smooth vector field $\text{grad}_g\,  f$ on $M$ such that for all smooth vector fields $Y$ on $M$, $$g(\text{grad}_g\,  f, Y) = df(Y).$$

Answer (score 1):

The Killing metric is a natural choice for any compact semi-simple group. It is bi-invariant therefore induces a natural $G$ invariant metric on any homogenous space $G/K$. But other choices are useful. Indeed, any $K$ invariant quadratic form on the Lie algebra of $G$ induces a invariant metric on $G/K$. In the case of $G/T$ you obtain a family of Kähler $G$-invariant metrics.

Comment: I'm interested just in the case where $G$ is compact Lie group (not necessarily semi-simple), and  of the manifold  $G/T$, where $T$ is a maximal torus. Could you please elaborate further about this case ?

Comment: I realize from your last sentence "In the case of $G/T$ you obtain a family of kähler $G$-invariant metrics", that I forgot to mention in my post that  $G/T$ was identified with a coadjoint orbit $G.r$, where $r$ is a regular element, sorry for that! I'll edit my question.